# Angular Material overflow issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a document viewer application for internal use, using angular and spring boot. The codebase works fine on modern browsers like chrome...the problem I'm having is that it has a few major issues displaying on IE (Which we have to support).

In chrome, the table angular material component looks like this. 
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUZy6.png)

In IE, the same table looks like this;
[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvANn.png)
(There are other issues here with icons not loading but that's a question for another time)

This is being caused by an overflow-x property being read differently in both browsers. This value is not something that has been deliberately set on my end, so I'm wondering if there's anything really stupid I'm missing that's causing this to happen.

To summarise the question. Is there anything I can do to stop IE from interpreting this value differently, or is there a specific styling I can add to the component to create a similar effect?

Comment: Can you create and share a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz?

Comment: Try to be more specific. What table are you using?

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? Besides, with only the description and the screenshots, we can't locate the issue. Please provide [a minimal code sample which can reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and can see how to help.